# Is it possible to create a superposition in IBMQ QISkit which has probability amplitudes $|a|\neq |b|$?

Tags: quantum-state, programming, qiskit

For example, we can create a single qubit state with a polar angle of $\pi/2$ with the Hadamard gate. But, can we create a state such as this,

$$\Psi = \cos(\pi/8)|0\rangle + \sin(\pi/8)|1\rangle$$

where the polar angle does not equal $\pi/2$, in QISkit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the [standard rotations](https://qiskit.org/documentation/terra/summary_of_quantum_operations.html#standard-rotations). In this case, you're looking for the `ry` operator (rotation around the y-axis). To rotate the state vector counter-clockwise around the unit circle by $\theta$, call `ry` with $2\theta$ or in your case $\frac{2\pi}{8}$ applied to state $|0\rangle$.

```
from qiskit import *
import numpy as np
q = QuantumRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q)
qc.ry(2*np.pi/8,q)
```